# Are levelwise endofunctors of simplicial sets homotopical?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $Set$  be the category of sets and $sSet$ the category of simplicial sets (the category of functors from $\mathbb{\Delta}^{op}$ to $Set$). Every functor $F:Set \to Set$ induces a functor $\hat{F}:sSet\to sSet$ by post-composition with $F$.

> **Question**: Is it always true that $F$ preserves weak homotopy equivalences of simplicial sets?

I can't find a reason why it should or an example that it doesn't. The question is just out of curiosity, but I would also like to understand how does one approach such a question.

One particular functor I am thinking about is the power set functor $P$ (as a covariant functor) that takes every set to the set of its subsets and acts on morphisms by taking direct image of subsets. Does $\hat{P}$ preserve weak equivalences? If so, does it have a known homotopical meaning?

Comment: It's hard to answer the question for _weak_ homotopy equivalences. But _simplicial_ homotopy equivalences are often preserved: it suffices that $F$ preserve binary products and $\hat{F} \Delta^1$ be a connected simplicial set.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Though there are also lots of functors that don't satisfy your conditions and still preserve (weak) homotopy equivalences like a coproduct with a constant set.

Comment: Sure. That endofunctor on $\mathbf{sSet}$ you get from that is simplicially enriched, and simplicially enriched functors always preserve simplicial homotopy equivalences.